# Figuring out discrete or continuous image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision

I have two images. One is continuous and another one is discrete. I would like to automatically figure out that which one is discrete (flag: 1) and which one is continuous (flag: 0). Both of my images as in matlab and 2D (not rgb).

[image]

Comment: You can count the number of different colors in the image and compare with a threshold

Comment: Yes, agree. But I really don't know that how this threshold should be ! (its number), because I may have a discrete image with high number of the classes.

Comment: Then you should perhaps use a measure of average distance between all colors of the image. I mean something analogous to standard deviation. But computing (perceptual) distance between colors is tricky

Comment: @LuisMendo If you are comparing two images, why not just call the image with more colors the "continuous" and the other "discrete"?

Comment: @chappjc Great idea! The OP says "One is continuous and another one is discrete."

Answer (score 2):

Following @chappjc's nice idea: the continuous image is the one that has more colors, and the other is the discrete one.

```
img1 = rand(100,200,3); %// example continuous image
img2 = randi(5,100,200,3)/10; %// example discrete image

[m1 n1 p1] = size(img1);
c1 = size(unique(reshape(img1, m1*n1, p1), 'rows'),1); %// number of colors
[m2 n2 p2] = size(img2);
c2 = size(unique(reshape(img2, m2*n2, p2), 'rows'),1); %// number of colors

if c1>c2
    disp('First image is continuous, second is discrete')
else
    disp('First image is discrete, second is continuous')
end
```

Comment: Ah, yes... color. What was I thinking?  :)

Comment: @chappjc I wrote my answer because I thought you weren't answering... please go ahead and I'll delete mine. The idea was yours!

Comment: In this code we always should have two images!! But, I only have one image and just want to figure our it is continuous or discrete

Comment: @Nicole That's a _different_ question. Your question said "I have two images. One is continuous and another one is discrete". You should try to write your question properly from the beginning

Comment: @Luis: I just wanted to show that what my mean is by discrete and continuous image !